# Pass a argument to a function callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, lodash

I'm trying to use debounce in lodash to delay the onChange, see the code below.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { TopBar } from "@shopify/polaris";
import { debounce } from "lodash";

function SearchBar() {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  const handleSearchFieldChange = ((value:string) => {
    setSearchValue(value);
  });

  const debounceLoadData = useCallback(debounce({searchValue} => fetchData, 1000), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    debounceLoadData();
    console.log({searchValue})
  }, [searchValue]);

  function fetchData(value:string) {
    console.log("searchValue " + value);
  }

  const searchFieldMarkup = (
    <TopBar.SearchField
      onChange={handleSearchFieldChange}
      value={searchValue}
      placeholder="Search Value"
    />
  );

  return <TopBar searchField={searchFieldMarkup} />;
}
```

In the beginning, I was tring to use `searchValue` in fetchData function but seems because of scope, it failed to read it, it was always empty though the state had been updated.

As a result, I try to pass it in from the `debounceLoadData` but I don't know how I can do that as what in useCallback is a function invocation. How can I pass `searchValue` in `fetchData` inside `debounce`.

Comment: Perhaps you should get the `fetchData` function working first, without any debouncing or throttling, then make the determination if performance improvements are necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lodash debounce takes in a function as the first argument. You can simply use `fetchData` as the function and pass on the `searchValue` to `debounceLoadData` which will then be passed to `fetchData` on invocation

```
const debounceLoadData = useCallback(debounce(fetchData, 1000), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    debounceLoadData(searchValue);
    console.log({searchValue})
  }, [searchValue]);
```

debounce actually returns a function, think of debounce as being implemented like

```
function debounce(func, wait) {
  let timeout
  return function(...args) {
    const context = this
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), wait)
  }
}
```

So basically `debounceLoadData` is the returned function here and `arguments passed to it i.e ...args` are being then passed to original function fetchData like `func.apply(context, args)`

Also `debounceLoadData` is created only once as the callback dependency is `[]`, you whether you pass it to useEffect as a dependency of not will not make any difference.

Please read this post for missing dependency warning

[How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect React Hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook/55854902#55854902)

Comment: How does the value passing work? I figured this out but I don't undertstand. Also I see a output in console ```React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'debounceLoadData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps```

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: @user1888955 Just keep one thing on mind, what goes into `debounce` comes out the same, in terms of function signature. `debounce` just add the super power of delaying to that function. The function itself remain the same. E.g. `debounce(x => x +1)` comes out the same function `x => x + 1`.

Answer (score 2):

I never like `useCallback`, it's quite a confusing hook, and I always use `useMemo` instead since it totally covers what `useCallback` can do (but not the other way around).

```
function SearchBar() {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  const handleSearchFieldChange = ((value:string) => {
    setSearchValue(value);
  });

  const debounceLoadData = useMemo(() => debounce(fetchData, 1000), []);
  /**
   * the equivalent of useCallback should be:
   *
   * const debounceLoadData = useCallback(debounce(fetchData, 1000), []);
   * 
   * But I really advice against it!
   * There's unnecessary function invocation compared to useMemo.
   */


  useEffect(() => {
    debounceLoadData(searchValue);  // <- you should pass in arg
    console.log({searchValue})
  }, [searchValue]);

  // ...
}
```

Yet for your case I don't think using lodash debounce is the best solution.

There's a hidden risk that the final invocation of effect `fetchData` happens AFTER your component is unmounted. And if `fetchData` contains some state mutation logic, that would raise an error of "Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component." which is not destructive but not optimal either.

I suggest manually debounce call using `setTimeout/clearTimeout`. It's pretty simple:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => fetchData(searchValue), 1000)
  return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId)
}, [searchValue])
```

Comment: I marked @ShubhamKhatri 's answer as I used useCallback. But I think you are right about just using setTimeout.

Comment: It's fine, glad to help out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused by the functional `setState` syntax. Try this:

```
const debounceLoadData = useCallback(() => debounce(() => fetchData(searchValue), 1000), []);
```

Comment: No you're confusing useCallback with useMemo. Your code is for useMemo.